# r raster levelplot code works standalone but not in a for loop

Tags: r, r-raster

Here's a simplified script that illustrates the problem. It creates 3 random rasters, puts their names in a character vector and then attempts to plot each of them in a for loop over the items in the character vector.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
r1 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(1)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))

r2 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(2)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))

r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(3)
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3))

rList <- c("r1", "r2", "r3")
#     levelplot(thi.ruminant, main = "THI, ruminants, monthly average, 1976-2016",  par.settings = mapTheme)

for (m in 1:length(rList)) {
  titleText <- paste0("test, ", gsub("thi.", "", rList[m]))
  print(titleText)
  levelplot(x = get(rList[m]), main = titleText)
}
```

Run the whole script and it prints out the three titles but no graphics. If you just assign m a value between 1 and 3 and then run `levelplot(x = get(rList[m]), main = titleText)` you get a nice looking graphic.

I'm doing this on a mac with Catalina and in RStudio but the same thing happens if I run it in a shell.

Comment: If you are plotting in a for loop you need to wrap `print()` around your call to `levelplot()`. However this will still overwrite all the plots and retain only the plot from the last iteration of the loop, unless you write the plots to a file within the loop.

Comment: Perfect! Except that in RStudio it actually keeps all three plots in the plot tab, lower left. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There are already a lot of similar or duplicate questions, try to search "r plot for loop" or something similar